# How to extract date from the filename in ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I need to populate a column in a db table based on the date from the filename (or sysdate).

Example 1 -> test_1_20200101.csv -> the column should have 20200101

Example 1 -> test_2.csv -> the column should be populated with today's date.

This is my expression when creating the derived column, but the column is always blank.

```
coalesce(regexExtract(replace(sourceFileName, '/'), `((\d{4}(?:\d{1})?)(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-1]))`, 1), toString(currentDate(), 'ddMMyyyy'))
```

Also I am bit confused if the regex is wrong or there's something wrong with the expression.

Thanks

CP.

Comment: Did you test the regex as a standalone expression in a tool like Regex Tester?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`CASE`** statement in derived column to extract date from file.

Below example depicts data flow with 2 files,

1. one having date in the file name
2. second without date in the file name.

**Sample Input files**:

1. test_1_20200101.csv
2. test_2.csv

**In source**:

1. Add a column (SourceFileName) to store file name in source.

[image]

2. Source data preview:

   a. Columns “id” and “description” are from the source files.

   b. Column **SourceFileName** is added to store source file name.

[image]

3. Add new column using derived column **FileExtractDate** to extract and store date from the source file name. If file name does not contain date, populating the current date using case statement.

   ```
   case(isDate(reverse(substring(reverse(SourceFileName), instr(reverse(SourceFileName), '.')+1,8)), 'yyyyMMdd'),reverse(substring(reverse(SourceFileName), instr(reverse(SourceFileName), '.')+1,8)), toString(currentDate(), 'yyyyMMdd'))
   ```

[image]

4. FileExtractDate is the results populated from the derived column.

[image]

**Sink**:

Date preview of sink shows all the columns from the source and additional columns SourceFileName and FileExtractDate which is the date extracted from file name or the current date.

[image]